# Expand and collapse using sigma.js

Tags: javascript, graph, graph-visualization, sigma.js

### Goal

I am trying to implement expand and collapse in [sigma.js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js). On right click of any node it's adding the new node and connects its edge, but it is placed in random position.

I want to add nodes in free space and they should not collide nor overlap with other nodes. It should expand slowly with an animation, expanding in free space area like [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130). [Related](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/905).

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Airlines Graph Render </title>
    <script src="../build/sigma.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js"></script>

    <script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/worker.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/supervisor.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/settings.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.curve.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.def.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.curvedArrow.js"></script>
    <style>
        body,html{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%
        }
        #graph-container {
          width:100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

      <div id="graph-container"></div>

    <script >
        
        var graph = {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "city": "Dallas",
                        "area": 999,
                        "code": 214,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Austin",
                        "area": 1180,
                        "code": 512,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "New York",
                        "area": 1214,
                        "code": 646,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Washington",
                        "area": 176,
                        "code": 564,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Atlanta",
                        "area": 342,
                        "code": 518,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Huston",
                        "area": 1625,
                        "code": 281,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Chicago",
                        "area": 606,
                        "code": 312,
                        "country": "USA"
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "London",
                        "area": 909,
                        "code": 312,
                        "country": "England"
                    }
                ],
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "key": 1,
                        "source": "Dallas",
                        "destination": "Austin",
                        "distance": 200,
                        "airlines": "British Airways",
                        "fare": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 2,
                        "source": "Austin",
                        "destination": "Dallas",
                        "distance": 200,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 120
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 3,
                        "source": "Washington",
                        "destination": "Dallas",
                        "distance": 1300,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 4,
                        "source": "Atlanta",
                        "destination": "Washington",
                        "distance": 600,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 600
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 5,
                        "source": "Washington",
                        "destination": "Atlanta",
                        "distance": 600,
                        "airlines": "KLM",
                        "fare": 400
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 6,
                        "source": "New York",
                        "destination": "Atlanta",
                        "distance": 300,
                        "airlines": "Qatar",
                        "fare": 1300
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 7,
                        "source": "Huston",
                        "destination": "Atlanta",
                        "distance": 800,
                        "airlines": "Indigo",
                        "fare": 400
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 8,
                        "source": "Atlanta",
                        "destination": "Huston",
                        "distance": 800,
                        "airlines": "Spicejet",
                        "fare": 600
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 9,
                        "source": "New York",
                        "destination": "Chicago",
                        "distance": 1000,
                        "airlines": "Air China",
                        "fare": 500
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 10,
                        "source": "Chicago",
                        "destination": "New York",
                        "distance": 1000,
                        "airlines": "Jet Airways",
                        "fare": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 11,
                        "source": "Dallas",
                        "destination": "Chicago",
                        "distance": 900,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 1300
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 12,
                        "source": "Austin",
                        "destination": "Huston",
                        "distance": 160,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 240
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 13,
                        "source": "Dallas",
                        "destination": "New York",
                        "distance": 780,
                        "airlines": "Lufthansa",
                        "fare": 300
                    }
                ]
            };
        var g = {
            nodes:[],
            edges:[]
        }

    // Generate a random graph:
        
            colors = [
              '#617db4',
              '#668f3c',
              '#c6583e',
              '#b956af'
            ];
         sigma.utils.pkg('sigma.canvas.nodes');
         sigma.canvas.nodes.border = function(node, context, settings) {
              var prefix = settings('prefix') || '';

              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(
                node[prefix + 'x']+15,
                node[prefix + 'y'],
                node[prefix + 'size']-2,
                0,
                Math.PI * 2,
                true
              );
              //context.fillStyle = "orange";
              context.strokeStyle = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor');
              //get the data from the group
              //var data = d3.select(this).data();
              context.stroke();
              //context.fill();
              context.font = "10px Arial";
              context.fillStyle = "black";
              context.strokeStyle = "black";
              //write the text in the context
              context.fillText(10,node[prefix + 'x']+15+ 10,  node[prefix + 'size']-2-15);

              // Adding a border
              //context.lineWidth = node.borderWidth || 1;
              //context.strokeStyle = node.borderColor || '#fff';
              //context.stroke();

              context.fillStyle = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor');
              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(
                node[prefix + 'x'],
                node[prefix + 'y'],
                node[prefix + 'size'],
                0,
                Math.PI * 2,
                true
              );

             context.closePath();
             context.fill();

            };

        for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++)
          g.nodes.push({
            id: graph.nodes[i]['city'],
            label: graph.nodes[i]['city'],
            x: Math.random(),
            y: Math.random(),
            size: 8,
            color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
          });

        for (var i = 0; i < graph.edges.length; i++)
          g.edges.push({
            id: graph.edges[i]['key'],
            source: graph.edges[i]['source'],
            target: graph.edges[i]['destination'],
            size: 8,
            label:graph.edges[i]['airlines'],
            color: '#668e3e',
            type:'curvedArrow'
          });

        s = new sigma({
          graph: g,
          renderer: {
            container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
            type: 'canvas'
          },
          settings: {
            edgeLabelSize: 'proportional',
            minNodeSize: 1,
            maxNodeSize: 10,
            minEdgeSize: 0.1,
            maxEdgeSize: 2,
            enableEdgeHovering: true,
            edgeHoverSizeRatio: 2,
            defaultNodeType: 'border',
            defaultNodeColor:"#fff",
            mouseEnabled: true,
            touchEnabled: true
          }
        });

        //s.settings('autoRescale', false)

        s.startForceAtlas2({worker: true, barnesHutOptimize: false});
        s.stopForceAtlas2();

        s.bind('rightClickNode', function(e) {
                
              console.log(e.type, e.data.node.label, e.data.captor);
                var name = 'New City'+Math.random();
                s.graph.addNode({
                id: name,
                label: 'baai',
                x: Math.random(),
                y: Math.random(),
                size: 8,
                color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
              });
              s.graph.addEdge({
                id: name +Math.random(),
                source: e.data.node.id,
                target: name,
                size: 8,
                label:'bit'+Math.random(),
                color: '#668e3e',
                type:'curvedArrow'
              });
              
              // Edge with Already existing one
              s.graph.addEdge({
                id: name+Math.random(),
                source: 'Huston',
                target: name,
                size: 8,
                label:'New City'+Math.random(),
                color: '#668e3e',
                type:'curvedArrow'
              });           
            setTimeout(function(){
                s.refresh();
            },1000) 
            
        });
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Attempts

On click of node I place nodes around it in a circular way by continuously increasing radius. In [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sumeetpri/fony4chu/) you can see this. First click went good but on next click, it's getting one circle inside another. How much radius should I put so that it does not look like that (as in screenshot)?

[image]

On second click it positions relatively and becomes like this screenshot. But I want actual positioning instead of relative.

[image]

Comment: Running your code locally gives me a completely different visual of the graph, with borders, edges and texts that are not present in your screenshots. Are you sure all dependencies were loaded?

Comment: My question is basically  how to do expand collapse in sigma js . For this I i tried to place nodes around the selected node using sin cos formula . First click works fine when I click next you see above screenshot . It starts positioning relatively .

Comment: are you checking fiddle in which i am trying to create node around selected node or top example . To do expand collapse I am trying above screenshot stuff

Comment: Above example is actual graph in which I want expand collapse , below screenshot is the ways in which i want to expand and collapse . I am trying .@NadavS.

Comment: Hi @NadavS. , pardon me for my English . Is my question clear to you or need more clarification .  Actually I want to implement something like https://doc.linkurio.us/ogma/latest/examples/layout-incremental.html . Not looking for compete answer , but expanding part

Comment: Yes. I got your question. I just (a) don't get why your screenshots are what they are (the whole graph is supposed to be richer?), and (b) please don't spam me with upvotes. It doesn't motivate me.

Comment: Apologize ! For upvote .  In screenshot I am trying to place direct child nodes in circle . This was an attempt to achieve expand collapse behavior . On  click I add x +random to create radius . First click circle formed well but in subsequent clicks already formed goes inside the other . How much radius I should increase so that it does not look like 2nd screenshot and be on same plane .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Fruchterman Reingold** Force-directed graph layout <sup>([algorithm summary](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Fruchterman-Reingold))</sup> is representing the forces between nodes as springs connecting steel rings, and is constantly trying to find balance between all nodes.
It is [available as a plugin in Linkurious](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/develop/plugins/sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold) (fork of Sigma.js). This layout may be just what you need.

Using your own code, and *only* the following dependencies:
`sigma.plugins.animate
sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold` (from Linkurious fork)

I got the following graph visualization:
[image: Fruchterman-Reingold layout version of the OP code]
[image: Slightly-changed behavior of node spawning]

To achieve this, where you initiated the Force Atlas 2 layout, replace it with the following:

```
sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.configure(sigmaInstance, {easing: 'quadraticOut'});
sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.start(sigmaInstance);
```

and, the most important part, right after you spawn a new node or remove a node, you have to re-run the layout:

```
sigmaInstance.refresh();
sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.start(sigmaInstance);
```

Now, a few tips

- There is no real need to `setTimeout()` to make it work. Just remember to re-run the force layout after each graph update.
- Your code seems to reproduce a much richer visualization than what your screenshots show - with curved edges, labels, etc. Make sure all the dependencies were actually loaded.
- If you do use curved edges, the force layout will still work correctly, but the representation may be a bit weird, so consider not using it.
- The Fruchterman-Reingold layout can be configured with custom duration, gravity force, easing methods, etc. Read its documentation to achieve its full power.

Comment: I tried adding gravity to fructermanReingold like below but nodes are getting apart     sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.start(s, { easing: 'linearNone', gravity:0.2}  );

Comment: Note that Linkurious is now DEPRECATED, see their new library [Ogma](https://linkurio.us/blog/ogma-js-library-large-scale-graph-visualization).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using position `Math.random`, set the position to be close to the node that was clicked and let the force layout take care of moving it away into the correct position. So, you should change this:

```
s.graph.addNode({
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
```

to that:

```
s.graph.addNode({
    x: clickedNode.x + 2* Math.random() - 1,
    y: clickedNode.y + 2* Math.random() - 1,
```

Comment: It is placing nodes to right , but forced layout is not happening automatically . Also running forced layout re-structure  all nodes . If it has lot of node positing new nodes always to right might not be  correct ?

Comment: Can we write logic to move clicked node move away from current position to free space and expand around it (  Like circle around )

Comment: the logic was putting them in any position around the node.  that will tend towards circles around them most times.